# Rank inequality of a partitioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be $\mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ that can be partitioned as
$$A:=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
 A_{1} & A_{2} \\
 A_{3} & A_{4}  \end{array}
 \right]$$
where $A_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times d_1}$, $A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times d_2}$,
$A_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_2 \times d_1}$, $A_4 \in \mathbb{R}^{n_2 \times d_2}$, where $n=n_1 + n_2$, $d = d_1 +d_2$.

Show that $rank(A) \leq rank(A_1)+rank(A_2)+rank(A_3)+rank(A_4)$.

Without loss of generality, suppose $d \leq n$, so I know that that $rank(A) \leq min(n, d) = d $. But I am not sure how to proceed with relating to the rank ofother smaller matrices afterwards. Any hints/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you started with an easier case: $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 A_2 \end{bmatrix}$, where $A_1$ and $A_2$ have the same number of rows. The rank of $A$ is the dimension of the columnspace (or rowspace, equivalently). Can you see why $\operatorname{rank} A \le \operatorname{rank} A_1 + \operatorname{rank} A_2$? You can also think about $\begin{bmatrix} A _1 \\ A_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I can come up with an example where $rank A \leq rankA_1 + rank A_2$ but not quite able to see how to prove it formally

Comment: The columns of $A$ are just the columns of $A_1$ and $A_2$ put together. If you reduce the columns of $A_1$ to a basis for the columnspace of $A_1$, then there will be $\operatorname{rank}A_1$ such columns remaining (and similarly for $A_2$). If you put these two bases together, you’ll have $\operatorname{rank}A_1 +\operatorname{rank}A_2$ column vectors spanning the columnspace of $A$ (a little proof might be good here). We can reduce this spanning set to a basis consisting of $\operatorname{rank}A$ vectors, proving the inequality.